# Why Running Test, Visual Studio executes full solution Rebuild

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This problem is only when I right-click on exact test, and call Run Tests.

When I build projects, including project with tests, VS build only dependencies.

Is this normal?

Comment: Why should it build projects that won't be executed?

Comment: I have no idea, it start building Web Site, which even cannot be referenced.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. The answer to your question body: yes, it is normal. Visual Studio only builds the current project and its dependencies (by default). If this seems a problem to you, you should specify why that is a problem.

Comment: I am asking: I have solution with 60 projects, and 1 of them is UnitTest pointing to 2 project. But "Run Tests" button, calls rebuilding of 60 projects. WHY? IS IT NORMAL? So yes - read body with header!